# Answers explicitly allowing and Users politely adding additional code

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

In [this Suggest Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8413465) for an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254957/how-to-create-a-gradient-in-spritekit), a user posted an Objective-C version of the RubyMotion solution.

Normally, I would have rejected the edit very quickly, but the original author of the answer wrote "[if] someone wants to edit this and put the objective c equivalent, go ahead", which made me pause and think a bit.  I ultimately decided on "Attempt to Reply" since I thought the author's allowance meant it didn't conflict with answer's intent and would potentially be better as an answer.

With my "Attempt to Reply", it was ultimately rejected with two "clearly conflicts with author's intent".

And this led me to some questions:

- Does this edit conflict with the author's intent since the author gave allowance of the addition?
- Is giving such an allowance good or bad practice on StackOverflow?
- If desiring to give such an allowance, would it have been better to post the answer under the  Community Wiki?
- Is there a mechanism of which I am unaware for transitioning the edit to or informing the Editor to transition the edit to an answer?

Comment: Why did you vote to reject it at all?

Comment: @BenVoigt  Because I though it "would potentially be better as an answer."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. No. The author explicitly invited such edits.
2. It's fine. Why not?
3. Yes - that drops the editing privilege down to [100 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), making it beyond the judgment of reviewers like yourself for many more editors. This is the decision of the author however, and if he wishes to retain ownership of the post he may opt to avoid it.
4. **Once approved**, editors can be addressed in comments by prefixing their name with @ - see: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) Note that this *only* works if the edit is approved - so you kinda shot yourself in the foot with this one.

Comment: Okay.  My main concern when thinking about the edit was a policy or unwritten rule about maintaining a clear separation of authorship for a single answer.  Since the Answer-er could potentially be put in a situation where they have to deal with code they didn't write (and which may not work), I didn't know if this practice was allowed or even encouraged.  I also know how @ works but really don't think I shot myself in the foot.

Comment: The last editor is always explicitly identified along with the author below a post, and the full revision history gives credit to all contributors - I don't normally stress about adding information to answers. Note that you can also address editors via the "causes harm" option when rejecting an edit, but of course you should only do so if the edit is actually *harmful*. And of course, don't hesitate to just skip edits that you're not comfortable making a call on.

Comment: Didn't see this discussion that back. In case anyone is confused when Shog says "The author explicitly invited such edits", remember that by posting on SE you are implicitly also inviting edits to your posts. CC-BY-SA and all that.